# solr 7.3.0 authorization is not working without zookeeper

Tags: solr

I am using Solr 7.3.0 in Standalone mode in windows 10 and enabled Basic Auth and Role based Authorization. There are 2 users I created, 1 is admin and another user "tom" to which I want to give access to only query the data or create/update data. He shouldn't be able to open admin UI or make any change in admin UI. Below is the security.json where this setup is done but not working. user "tom" is able to login to admin UI and make changes, query and read all the cores data. Please help me with what I am doing wrong.

```
{
  "authentication": {
    "blockUnknown": true,
    "class": "solr.BasicAuthPlugin",
    "credentials": {
      "solr": "IV0EHq1OnNrj6gvRCwvFwTrZ1+z1oBbnQdiVC3otuq0= Ndd7LKvVBAaZIF0QAVi1ekCfAJXr1GGfLtRUXhgrF8c=",
      "tom": "qiO9mRn2s1CJLanzz+dHaAyEisSvUM41Jd3mox+LKHM= Vh9irc/tc7eC/j3p9UFYITvlWup7vROaviAaWiSh0QA="
    },
    "": {
      "v": 0
    }
  },
  "authorization": {
    "class": "solr.RuleBasedAuthorizationPlugin",
    "permissions": [
      {
        "name": "security-edit",
        "role": "admin",
        "index": 1
      },
      {
        "name": "collection-admin-read",
        "role": "xz",
        "index": 2
      },
      {
        "name": "collection-admin-edit",
        "role": "xz",
        "index": 3
      }
    ],
    "user-role": {
      "solr": "admin",
      "tom": "xz"
    },
    "": {
      "v": 0
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Where have you put the file? Have you tested [with `blockUnknown` set](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/basic-authentication-plugin.html) as well?

Comment: the file i have put under $Solr_HOME/server/solr. i have tried with blockUnknown as false also but same result

Comment: I've been having the same issue trying to get your file to work - but I think using `collection-admin-*` is not what you're looking for - probably just `read` and `update`. Does it do what want if you use Solr in cloud mode and test there?

Comment: I tried with read and update also but it was same issue and I am able to access Solr Admin UI using that user.